# How can I default constants in IntelliJ to private?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I am creating a constant in IntelliJ (using Ctrl+Alt+C), by default it is `public static final`. How can I make it `private static final` instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, press this shortcut again, which shows dialog with more options.

There is a visibility section. If you select private here, it will be the new default when extracting constants the next time.

See the IntelliJ IDEA documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/extract-constant.html

[image: introduce constant dialogue]

Comment: For Mac users, it's usually `Cmd+Option+C`